# Elastic search Average time difference Aggregate Query

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl, elasticsearch-query

I have documents in elasticsearch in which each document looks something like as follows:

```
{
  "id": "T12890ADSA12",
  "status": "ENDED",
  "type": "SAMPLE",
  "updatedAt": "2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z",
  "events": [
    {
      "event": "STARTED",
      "version": 1,
      "timestamp": "2020-04-30T13:41:25.862Z"
    },
    {
      "event": "INPROGRESS",
      "version": 2,
      "timestamp": "2020-05-14T17:03:09.137Z"
    },
    {
      "event": "INPROGRESS",
      "version": 3,
      "timestamp": "2020-05-17T17:03:09.137Z"
    },
    {
      "event": "ENDED",
      "version": 4,
      "timestamp": "2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z"
    }
  ],
  "createdAt": "2020-04-30T13:41:25.862Z"
}
```

Now, I wanted to write a query in elasticsearch to get all the documents which are of type "SAMPLE" and I can get the average time between STARTED and ENDED of all those documents. Eg. Avg of (2020-05-29T18:18:08.483Z - 2020-04-30T13:41:25.862Z, ....). Assume that STARTED and ENDED event is present only once in events array. Is there any way I can do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this. The query selects the events of type SAMPLE and status ENDED (to make sure there is a ENDED event). Then the `avg` aggregation uses scripting to gather the STARTED and ENDED timestamps and subtracts them to return the number of days:

```
POST test/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "filter": [
        {
          "term": {
            "status.keyword": "ENDED"
          }
        },
        {
          "term": {
            "type.keyword": "SAMPLE"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "duration": {
      "avg": {
        "script": "Map findEvent(List events, String type) {return events.find(it -> it.event == type);} def started = Instant.parse(findEvent(params._source.events, 'STARTED').timestamp); def ended = Instant.parse(findEvent(params._source.events, 'ENDED').timestamp); return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(started, ended);"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The script looks like this:

```
Map findEvent(List events, String type) {
  return events.find(it -> it.event == type);
}
def started = Instant.parse(findEvent(params._source.events, 'STARTED').timestamp);
def ended = Instant.parse(findEvent(params._source.events, 'ENDED').timestamp); 
return ChronoUnit.DAYS.between(started, ended);
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. Is there a way to make it more generalized? Eg. avg time between any 2 states. Eg. STARTED and 1st INPROGRESS?

Comment: In my answer I've taken the first and last events, but you're free to pick any other events, it'd work the same way.

Comment: Yeah but for that, we need to know the position of the events in the array. Is there any way, we can find the position of events based on event type by using for loop?

Comment: @Val How to do the same for every bucket ?

Comment: @Garrick feel free to create a new question with your use case and potentially reference it here.

Comment: @Val This is the similar use case. Just one difference, for every bucket this needs to be done. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65630911/average-of-difference-between-the-dates)

Comment: this is great, how can we use this in Kibana? I want to do something similar for visualization.